# Menu icon visible in Chrome but not in Android's standard browser

Tags: css, svg, menu, hamburger-menu

The menu "hamburger" icon is not visible in the Android's standard browser (tested on a Samsung S5 and Samsung Note 2). But it does appear in Chrome and everything works perfectly.

Using an svg icon.

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__inner">
    <img class="header__logo" src="images/city.png" alt="iconic view of a cityscape">
    <h1 class="header__title">
      The Brighton Times
    </h1>
    <a id="menu" class="header__menu">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M2 6h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2z"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>

<nav id="drawer" class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And below the code in responsive.css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 549px) {
.header__logo {height: 48px;
margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.header__title {
margin-left: 0;
font-size: 2em;
vertical-align: bottom; 
}
.nav {
z-index: 10;
background-color: #fff;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
/* This trasform moves the drawer off canvas. */
-webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0);
transform: translate(-300px, 0);
/* Optionally, we animate the drawer. */
transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
.nav.open {
-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.nav__item {
display: list-item;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
.header__menu {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
padding: 1em;
}
.header__menu svg {
width: 32px;
fill: #000000;
}
}
```

Oh before I forget the whole right side in the standard browser is clickable/tappable. So no matter where you tap (as long as it's on the right side of screen), the menu (drawer) appears.

I can't seem to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, reading, waiting I finally found an answer to my own question. Who wants to use an svg icon if png is a much better choice? Solution:

Instead of

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M2 6h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2zm0 5h20v3H2z"/>
  </svg>
```

just use

```
<img src="/images/icon.png" height="32" width="32">
```

For noobs like myself. You can download a hamburger icon from iconfinder.com save it as png (tip: at least 128px and scale it down (see img src code)).

And there you have it. Works on all browsers. Problem solved.

And to think that this code is from a course initiated by Google. It's ironic, because their own design doesn't work well in their own Android's browser.